# I still can't understand how routers work

Tags: router, interface

I've seen a topology that has 1 router for each network, for example:

Network1: 192.168.1.0
192.168.1.2/24 PC1 ->
192.168.1.3/24 PC2 -> 192.168.1.5/24 SWITCH -> 192.168.1.1/24 ROUTER
192.168.1.4/24 PC3 ->

Network2: 192.168.2.0
192.168.2.2/24 PC1 ->
192.168.2.3/24 PC2 -> 192.168.2.5/24 SWITCH 192.168.2.1/24 ROUTER
192.168.2.4/24 PC3 ->

So clearly we can see that each PC's FastEthernet is connected to each router's interface, and from my understanding, a router's job is to connect networks together, i.e. connect 192.168.1.0 and 192.168.2.0 together and not multiple devices. In summary, my question is: do each interface in a router have independent ip address/network or they are basically an ethernet interfaces that connect multiple devices in a single network?

Comment: Each router interface in in a separate network because routers route packets between networks. What you seem to have is off-topic consumer-grade devices that are Frankenstein boxes that have several devices, including a switch in the chassis, which is why the PCs, connected to the "router' can be in the same network.

Comment: Oh yeah, i made a mistake, there is a Switch between the PC's and the Router. The PC's are connected to the switch and not the router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In summary, my question is: do each interface in a router have independent ip address/network[...]?

Yes.  Each interface on a router has an address on each separate network.

In your example, you have two separate routers on two separate networks.  As you've described them, they are independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Router is layer3 devices operates on network layer of osl model . Router mainly works on based on routing table build in routers to forward packet to next node router looks into routing table if route is available then it will forward packet to destination based on next hop or exist interface available on particular route .

And it's has arp table also with ipaddress mapped to Mac address table . This scenario will be used when router wants to forward packet to layer2 switch..